# TActionMainMenuBar and TActionToolbar lose settings

Tags: delphi, internet-explorer-9, photoshop

I stumbled across a really weird behavior recently. When I use a TActionMainMenuBar (or a TActionToolBar) in my program, compile and run, and then start Photoshop CS5 or Internet Explorer 9, the ActionMainMenuBar (and ActionToolBar) loses all its settings. The colors defined in the assigned colormap disappear and the font settings are also lost. Has anyone seen this before and knows a workaround?

D2007 Pro (all updates applied), D2010 Pro (all updates applied), Vista Home Premium 32 bit, NVidia GForce 8600 GT, latest driver installed.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Drop a TActionManager and a TActionMainMenuBar on a form
2. Create a category with some menu items
3. Drag category onto ActionMainMenuBar
4. Assign TwilightColorMap to the ActionMainMenuBar
5. Run program
6. Start IE9 or Photoshop CS5
7. Watch all predefined settings disappear (you have to close IE9 again to see the effect)

If you start Photoshop or IE first and then the Delphi program, nothing happens. The bug is also present when in design mode in the IDE. A fellow developer has already confirmed the described behavior for his system with Win7 Pro 32bit and a ATI Radeon 9800 Pro.

Thx for any comments/ solutions

Phil

PS: Using Photoshop CS3 doesn't produce this bug

Comment: ouch, most likely a registry setting... try searching the source code for Registry, see where is the "save/load" implementation and make a workaround...

Comment: When you say that your ActionMainMenuBar 'loses all its settings' are you referring to property settings or images or event handlers or something else?

Comment: It's losing its property settings - in this case the colors that are defined in the colormap and the font settings.

Comment: Dorin, there's nothing written to the registry.

Comment: This behavior also seems to happen when you change the Windows visual style (tested on Windows 7). Example, in the Delphi IDE if you assign a Colormap to the TActionMainMenuBar and then change the Windows Visual Style the Colormap reverts to .DefaultColorMap

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one other way of reproducing the problem:

- Complete steps 1 to 4 as in the question (including dropping a TwilightColorMap).
- Add a button to the form with the code  `Perform(WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, 0);` in its click handler.
- Run the application and press the button.

So now we know that a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` broadcast might be causing the problem, we might wonder if launching IE produces the same:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ..
  protected
    procedure WMSettingChange(var Message: TWMSettingChange);
      message WM_SETTINGCHANGE;
    ..

procedure TForm1.WMSettingChange(var Message: TWMSettingChange);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToHex(Message.Flag, 4) + ', ' + Message.Section);
  inherited;
end;
```

After we run our application and then launch IE, a few seconds later the below appears in the memo:

> 0000, Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\SearchScopes

I have no idea what IE has to say to our form (and all other top-level windows) at every launch, and I don't know if it is doing this on every Windows box on earth or just yours and mine, but evidently the `ActionMainMenuBar`is no good at handling it.

A win control (the form), receiving a `WM_WININICHANGE`, performs a `CM_WININICHANGE` and upon receiving it broadcasts the same to all its controls. The below is how it is handled by the menu bar:

```
procedure TCustomActionMainMenuBar.CMWininichange(var Message: TWMWinIniChange);
begin
  inherited;
  RequestAlign;
  Font.Assign(Screen.MenuFont);
end;
```

Thinking that the system menu font could have been changed (the code should have looked for a 'WindowsThemeElement' or 'WindowMetrics' section in the message, but anyway..), it is reassigned from the refreshed `Screen.MenuFont`. The problem is, we weren't exactly using it.

Additionally the ColorMap responds to a `CM_WININICHANGE` by resetting its colors by calling its `UpdateColors` method. This is even [documented](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ActnMan.TCustomActionBarColorMap.UpdateColors):

> **UpdateColors** is called automatically when an ActionBand component receives a CM_WININICHANGE message.

---

So the solution would involve deciding what to do and overriding both behavior, I tried to comment the below solution for why I believe that it would be the correct solution:

```
type
  // Derive your own ColorMap that would reset its own colors.
  // This is an interposer for simplicity..
  TTwilightColorMap = class(actncolormaps.TTwilightColorMap)
  public
    procedure UpdateColors; override;
  published
    property Color default clGreen;
    property FontColor default clYellow;
    property MenuColor default $4488FF;
    // reintroduce as many property as necessary, probably all is necessary..
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ..
  private
    FSaveMenuFont: TFont; // will hold initial main menu bar's font settings
  protected
    procedure WMSettingChange(var Message: TWMSettingChange);
      message WM_SETTINGCHANGE;
  end;

..

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FSaveMenuFont := TFont.Create;
  FSaveMenuFont.Assign(ActionMainMenuBar1.Font);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FSaveMenuFont.Destroy;
end;

procedure TForm1.WMSettingChange(var Message: TWMSettingChange);
begin
  inherited;
  // The below are the *section*s that really changing system settings
  // would notify that I'm aware of, there may be more...
  if (Message.Section <> 'WindowsThemeElement')
      or (Message.Section <> 'WindowMetrics') then
    ActionMainMenuBar1.Font.Assign(FSaveMenuFont)
  else
    // Develop your logic here. The system menu font might really have been
    // changed. You can get it from Screen.MenuFont. But then if we had been
    // using the system font, the control already applies the change by default.

end;

procedure TTwilightColorMap.UpdateColors;
begin
  inherited;
  // Reset your colors, note that system colors might have been
  // changed or not. If changed, they should be reflected in 'cl..' constants.
  Color := clGreen;
  FontColor := clYellow;
  MenuColor := $4488FF;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks @Ken. As far as I can tell this won't be widely useful, as the ColorMap is not a widely used control. But it was fun :).

Comment: You never can tell... There are lots of people still using D7 and 2007 who don't have access to VCL styles that may use them. Still a nice job tracking down the problem. :)

Comment: Sertac, thanks a lot for pointing me into the right direction. Your workaround solves the issue with the font setting (you'll have to remove the "Inherited" from the TForm1.WMSettingChange procedure to make it work though), but has no effect on the changing color settings within the colormap. It's easy to check: run your test program directly from the Delphi IDE, focus back to the IDE, start IE9, close IE9 and watch the color setting of TwilightMap1 magically disappear...

Comment: Sorry, me again (I missed the 5 minute window to edit my comment above). The color settings do not disappear from the colormap, but the colors of the TActionMainMenuBar are not restored.

Comment: Reassigning the color properties doesn't seem to be the solution, I've just tried it.

Comment: @Phil - Forget the previous comment, look at the source of 'ActnColorMaps.pas', whenever a colormap recieves 'CM_WININICHANGE' `UpdateColors` is called. It should reall be called 'ResetColors'. Anyway, I believe the right solution would be to derive your colormap and override `UpdateColors`.

Comment: You're right, that looks like the way to go. Although I really hate to jump through so many hoops just to correct some odd behavior. Maybe I should update to XE2 after all. Do you know if I can assign a VCL style to a TActionMainMenuBar by any chance? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Phil - I really doubt updating will solve this... Yes, if I remember correctly action bands comply styles. I've updated the answer. See if it helps.

Comment: Sertac, just saw the updated answer. I'll give it a try and report back.

Comment: No dice... :(  The colors are not reset even when using the interposer class. Interestingly, I get a different message than you in Memo1 when I start and close IE9: "0000, _____________4______________________________________U___Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\LowRegistry\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\TabbedBrowsing"

Comment: @Phil - Put a breakpoint on your ColorMap descendant's `UpdateColors` method. If it's not hit when you launch ie, your code and mine is not same. You *have to* keep the `inherited` of `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` handler of the form of course..

Comment: The UpdateColors procedure does get executed and both the font face and font color of the ActionMainMenuBar are restored. All other colors that are defined in the TwilightColormap are not reset to the state they had before launching IE. Did you reintroduce *all* properties of the colormap in your code or just the three from your sample code?

Answer (score 4):

Found it! The problem was that the Colormap property of the ActionMainMenuBar1 is reset to ActionMainMenuBar1.DefaultColormap every time IE9 or Photoshop CS5 is started/closed. I will accept Sertac's solution as an answer because it pointed me into the right direction how to solve this issue.

Here's the final code. It works flawlessly (as far as I can tell) with both IE9 and Photoshop CS5 now.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ActnMan, ActnColorMaps, ActnList, ToolWin, ActnCtrls, ActnMenus,
  StdCtrls;


type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ActionManager1: TActionManager;
    ActionMainMenuBar1: TActionMainMenuBar;
    Action1: TAction;
    Action2: TAction;
    Action3: TAction;
    Action4: TAction;
    TwilightColorMap1: TTwilightColorMap;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ActionMainMenuBar1GetControlClass(Sender: TCustomActionBar;
      AnItem: TActionClient; var ControlClass: TCustomActionControlClass);
  protected
    procedure WMSettingChange(var Message: TWMSettingChange); message WM_SETTINGCHANGE;
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FSaveMenuFont: TFont; // will hold initial main menu bar's font settings
    FSaveColormap: TTwilightColormap;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}


// Fixing paint issue when IE9 was run and closed again

procedure TForm1.ActionMainMenuBar1GetControlClass(Sender: TCustomActionBar;
  AnItem: TActionClient; var ControlClass: TCustomActionControlClass);
begin
  ActionMainMenuBar1.ColorMap.Assign(FSaveColormap);
end;


procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FSaveMenuFont := TFont.Create;
  FSaveMenuFont.Assign(ActionMainMenuBar1.Font);
  FSaveColormap := TTwilightColormap.Create(Self);
  FSaveColormap.Assign(ActionMainMenuBar1.Colormap);
end;


procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FSaveMenuFont.Destroy;
  FSaveColormap.Destroy;
end;


procedure TForm1.WMSettingChange(var Message: TWMSettingChange);
begin
  inherited;
  // Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToHex(Message.Flag, 4) + ', ' + Message.Section);
  ActionMainMenuBar1.Font.Assign(FSaveMenuFont);
  // In case Photoshop CS5 was run and closed before
  ActionMainMenuBar1.ColorMap.Assign(FSaveColormap);
end;

end.
```

Thanks again everyone for your help.

Comment: Glad you have resolved it :) and thanks for posting your solution.

Comment: I finally managed to fix the paint problem for both IE9 and Photoshop CS5. Please see the updated code above. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't GetControlClass unnecessary now?

Comment: GetControlClass is necessary to fix the paint problem for IE9. Adding the code to the WMSettingChange procedure fixes the issue for Photoshop CS5 plus the problem with the font.